# How do I separate true positives and true negatives?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

Essentially I have a binary image which represents the ground truth and I have a binary image which is taken from the results of an algorithm - now the task was to find the overlapping regions to evaluate the performance of the algorithm, i.e. find the true positives (TPs), true negatives (TNs), false positives (FPs) and false negatives (FNs).

I have correctly found the values for FPs and FNs, however I cannot get my head around how I would separate the TNs and TPs.

The way I calculated the overlaps was by firstly working out the difference between the ground truth image and the algorithm's image:

```
% Gdilate=ground truth image, img=result of algorithm
ImageComparison = (Gdilate>0)-(img>0);
```

Then simply due to the subtraction I can sum up all the pixels that 0s, 1s and -1s to obtain the TP_TNs, FNs and FPs.

```
TP_TN = sum(sum(ImageComparison==0))/rows/columns;
FN = sum(sum(ImageComparison==-1))/rows/columns;
FP = sum(sum(ImageComparison==1))/rows/columns;
```

Here are the results of `imagesc()` on the `ImageComparison` variable:

[image: results of imagesc]

Now I just need to find a way to separate the TPs from the TNs, because they both appear as 0 in the `ImageComparison` matrix.

Answer (score 5):

The way that you are doing it cannot differentiate between true positives and true negatives because (`0 - 0` and `1 - 1`) are *both* equal to zero. Instead, if you have two binary results (`ground_truth` and `test_data`), you don't need to subtract the two, you can compute everything you need using just logical comparisons.

```
ground_truth = Gdilate > 0;
test_data = img > 0;
```

## False Positives

Negative in ground truth but positive in your test.

```
false_positives = ~ground_truth & test_data;
false_positive_rate = sum(false_positives(:)) / numel(false_positives);
```

## False Negatives

Positive in ground truth data but negative in your test

```
false_negatives = ground_truth & ~test_data;
false_negative_rate = sum(false_negatives(:)) / numel(false_negatives);
```

## True Positives

Positive in both

```
true_positives = ground_truth & test_data;
true_positive_rate = sum(true_positives(:)) / numel(true_positives);
```

## True Negatives

Negative in both

```
true_negatives = ~ground_truth & ~test_data;
true_negative_rate = sum(true_negatives(:)) / numel(true_negatives);
```

Comment: thanks so much! That makes sense and I see what you mean! Thanks again for the clear and concise answer.

Comment: @StacyLam if this answer was indeed the answer to your question, please consider marking it accepted by pressing the checkmark below the voting arrows on the top left of the question. This gives both you and Suever a bit of reputation and signals the community at large that you no longer need help with this question.