# How to plot a ROC curve of a detector generated by TrainCascadeObjectDetector?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, cascade, roc

in my project for object detection in images i use [TrainCascadeObjectDetector](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/train-a-cascade-object-detector.html) function of matlab you can see also [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/traincascadeobjectdetector.html), this function use opencv train cascade and is for training a set of images ( positives and negatives ):

positives: images contain the object of interest .

negatives: images dosen't contain the object of interest but must contain the backround of positives for more precision after training.

This function requier also some parameters:

-number of cascade Stages.

-True Positive Rate.

-false Alarm Rate.

-Negative Samples factor.

-Object Training Size.

-characteristic type (HOG,LBP,Haar).

I use the HOG  (histogram of oriented gradients), and the result of this function is an .xml file:

```
trainCascadeObjectDetector(outputXMLFilename,positiveInstances,negativeImages)
```

i use the output to localize the object of interest in images using:

```
detector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector(XMLFILE)
```

so i have in result a detector wich i use it to draw bounding boxes:

```
BBOX = step(detector)
```

I want to evalute the performance of my results, i found that is possible to draw a ROC curve, [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/283208-is-it-possible-to-plot-roc-curve-for-train-cascade-object-detector-result) my question.
The ROC is a true positive rate VS false positive rate curve, so it's requier value of TPR and FPR.
The global TPR and FPR is calculating in this way:

```
TruePositiveRate^numberOfStages    and FalseAlarmRate^numberOfStages
```

But they are just 2 values and not unalf to plot the curve.
I tried also to have TPR and FPR by doing a binary comparaison from this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36697809/how-do-i-separate-true-positives-and-true-negatives), i did it by comparing my ground truth images and result images and took the max FPR and TPR, Now i have 1 TPR and 1 FPR for the whole images of the final stage.
How to get the others from the previous stages?

My GUI:
[image]

Comment: you can vary the detection threshold to get different sensitivity values for the same classifier

Comment: if you want to evaluate different classifiers you can plot the "learnimg curve" which is "accuracy over number of used training samples"

Comment: There is 1 threshold  for each stage in the final .xml file, are these thresholds you talking about?

Comment: many classifiers compute some kind of score and from that score decide whether an object is found or not. If you vary that threshold you get different tp and fp rates. If yourclassifier doesnt allow to vary tp and fp rates easily by parameter change, a ROC might not be the right graph to compute. Typically ROC is just used to choose thr best threshold.

Comment: Some of the function inputs are true positive rate and false alarm rate for each stage, the global value are calculated like this : TruePositiveRate^numberOfStages    and FalseAlarmRate^numberOfStages , if ROC it's not the right graph, what is the right way to evalute the performance of my classifier by ploting a graph showing what make it better than other classifier generated by the same function?

Comment: if your tp and fr rates depend on the number of stages them vary the number of stages...

Comment: That was my question for @MSalters, """"Do you mean to run TrainCascadeObjectDetector many times with different numberOfstages, then apply the .xml files on the images then do the comparison with the ground truth? """"

Comment: so if i want to do the comparison on my GUI,then i must provide as inputs to a function  the .xml files trained in advance, this function as i said befor, to do the comparison between positives ground truth and results then will plot a graph.   because  my GUI perform training and showing result on test images, the training take a lot of time depend on the parametres and the images. @Micka i will provide i picture of my interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ROC is defined for parameterized classifiers, where every continuous parameter that influences FPR/TPR has its own curve. You can approximate this curve by repeatedly choosing different values of the parameter, and then running your validation set through your classifier.

Comment: Do you mean to run TrainCascadeObjectDetector many times with different numberOfstages, then apply the .xml files on the images then do the comparison with the ground truth? @MSalters

Comment: That is how you calculate the ROC for the NumberOfStages parameter; whether that specific ROC makes sense for you I cannot tell.

Comment: it's a lot of work to train classifier many times, although in opencv its easier, so if my training take 5 hours (GLAD I DID NOT CHOOSE LBP OR HAAR  :) ) to have 5 values for exemple of TPR and FPR it will take 15 hours.  is it the only why? @MSalters

Comment: I agree that ROC curves for training parameters are a lot more time consuming than ROC curves for simple classification parameters.